# The woocommerce_checkout_login_form() function is not working properly if I use the WooCommerce Notices Elementor widget in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

In same page if I use the Elementor widget (elementor pro widget) called **"Woocommerce Notices"** and my custom widget which contains **woocommerce_checkout_login_form()** function. In this page, **woocommerce_checkout_login_form()** function is not working properly.

**So far my findings:** **woocommerce_checkout_login_form()** function returns the essentials things as well as **"template/notices/notice.php"** code. This code contains the markup with **'woocommerce-info'** class and the Woocommerce Notices grab all the elements into the **'woocommerce-info'** class and render it to the Woocommerce Notices widget.

Thanks!

In same page I need to use Elementor widget called **Woocommerce Notices** and my custom widget which contains woocommerce_checkout_login_form() function.